# Js.erb renders only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Vote button in a hidden Div which is loaded using pirobox.The triggering link is :

```
<div class="inliner"><a href="#vid_<%=c.id%>" rel="inline-1000-500" class="pirobox_gall1"><h5><%=c.title%></h5></a></div>
```

and in the hidden div, i have the following for my vote button:

```
<%=button_to 'Vote',vote_path(:format=>:js,:id=>c.id),:remote=>true%>
```

and in the controller i have:

```
def vote
        @video=Video.find(params[:id])
        @video.increment!(:votes)

        respond_to do |format|

           format.js  { render :layout=>false }
        end

    end
```

finally in my js.erb, i have: `$('p#success_<%=@video.id%>').fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');`

when the trigger link is clicked, the pirobox is loaded with the hidden contents.When i click vote button, the vote is incremented and also the js.erb file is rendered.Everything works fine.
But,now i close the pirobox popup.Then trigger it again and click the vote button.The Vote field is incremented, but the js.erb is not rendered :(
How should i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clean a little your code;

Your button:

```
<%= button_to 'Vote', vote_path(c), :remote => true %>
```

Your controller:

```
def vote
  @video = Video.find(params[:id])
  @video.increment!(:votes)
end
```

your js:

```
$('#success_<%= @video.id %>').fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Now run `Firebug` and trace your ajax calls via cosole

Comment: Thanks for your response.There's no problem with Ajax.The issue is with the pirobox popup.I had to place the voting mechanism outside the priobox overlay.